# Gembox document HTML to PDF losing details

Tags: c#, html, pdf, gembox-document

I just dowloaded the newset version of gembox document in order to convert ah html file into PDF.
It seems to be working, but the resulting PDF is losing some information.

Here is what the HTML looks like:

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          .main-container {
            width: 383.62px;
            height: 576.95px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 96px 48px;
            font-family: Verdana; 
          }
          .code {
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
          }
          .mrg-btm {
            margin-bottom: 8px;
          }
          .name-and-code {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
          }
          .flex-div {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            width: 100%;
          }
          .distance-one {
            width: 50%;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 14px;
          }
          .distance-two {
            width: 50%;
            text-align: right;
            font-size: 14px;
          }
          .font-bold {
            font-weight: bold;
          }
          .scadenza {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
          }
          .data-scadenza {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
          }
          .materiali {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: left;
            letter-spacing: 5px;
          }
          .last-codes {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: left;
            font-family: TimesNewRoman; 
          }
          .mrg-btm-two {
            margin-bottom: 64px;
          }
          .mrg-btm-three {
            margin-bottom: 16px;
          }
          .mrg-btm-four {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
          }
          .mrg-rgt-one {
            margin-right: 20px;
          }
          .mrg-rgt-two {
            margin-right: 8px;
          }
          .mrg-rgt-three {
            margin-right: 16px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="main-container">
          <div class="code mrg-btm">
            <label>STM0583A0</label>
          </div>
          <div class="name-and-code mrg-btm-four">
            <label>TUNISI&nbsp;&nbsp;0583</label>
          </div>
         <div class="mrg-btm-four">
           <img alt='Barcode Generator TEC-IT'
           src='https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=02329747&code=Code39'/>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-div mrg-btm">
          <label class="distance-one">SqA</label>
          <label class="distance-two font-bold">2481m&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(#13)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-div mrg-btm-three">
          <label class="distance-one">GOMSET1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(#2)</label>
          <label class="distance-two">11/10/2022</label>
        </div>
        <div class="scadenza mrg-btm">
            <label>Scadenza</label>
        </div>
        <div class="data-scadenza mrg-btm">
            <label>31/10/2022</label>
        </div>
        <div class="materiali mrg-btm">
            <label>Materiali</label>
        </div>
        <div class="last-codes mrg-btm-two">
            <label class="mrg-rgt-one">RC1812</label>
            <label>000331799805</label>
        </div>
        <div class="last-codes mrg-btm">
            <label class="mrg-rgt-two">SB00040A0</label>
            <label class="mrg-rgt-two">STR1026420</label>
            <label>25/10/2022</label>
        </div>
        <div class="last-codes">
            <label class="mrg-rgt-two">C-1812</label>
            <label class="mrg-rgt-three">RC1812</label>
            <label>000331799805</label>
        </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the c# code. I tried several methods but none of them work.

```cs
    GemBox.Document.ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
    DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load(filenameHtml);
    document.Save(path + pdfFilename);
    //CODE 2
    GemBox.Document.ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
    string body = File.ReadAllText(filenameHtml);
    var htmlLoadOptions = new HtmlLoadOptions();
    using (var htmlStream = new MemoryStream(htmlLoadOptions.Encoding.GetBytes(body)))
    {
    var document = DocumentModel.Load(htmlStream, htmlLoadOptions);
    document.Save(path + pdfFilename);
    }
```

I tried also setting up some parameters, but in every test, the size of the area of the HTML was lost, the Times New Roman font as well, and also the flex div spacing some elements.

Here is what the original xml looks like:

[image]

And here is the result

[image]

What can I change to make the Gembox Document output look like the original?

Comment: Looking at the XML, it seems like your library does not support flex-div. Use an alternative XML layout mechanism.

Comment: Yes unfortunately the problem is that GemBox.Document currently doesn't support "flex" nor specifying size of block-level elements. There is an internal support ticket for this, but it won't be done this year. For now, I'm afraid you'll need to use some other layout, perhaps the `<table>` element that KJ mentioned.